# Pyscopg and Redshift, relation doesn't exists

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm connecting to Redshift with Psycopg with the following piece of code

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='events', host=myhost,
port=my_post, user=my_user, password=my_pwd)
```

Then, check if a table called "event" exists and I do that like so

```
def table_exists(con, table_str):
    #
    exists = False
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select exists(select relname from pg_class where relname='" + table_str + "')")
        exists = cur.fetchone()[0]
        cur.close()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)
    return exists

table_exists(con, "event")
```

Which returns `True`. However, when I try to read the table (for instance, below I try to return the column names) I get an error message saying that the "relation doesn't exists"

```
def get_table_col_names(con, table_str):
    #
    col_names = []
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from " + table_str + " LIMIT 0")
        for desc in cur.description:
            col_names.append(desc[0])
        cur.close()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)
    #
    return col_names

get_table_col_names(con, "event")
```

Can you point me in the direction of what's happening?

Comment: Is the table in the public schema?

Answer (score 0):

for me its working fine

```
import psycopg2
 rs_conn = psycopg2.connect(host='MYHOST',
                user='NAME',
                port='PORT NUM',
                password='PASS',
                dbname='DBNAME')
def get_table_col_names(con, table_str):
    col_names = []
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from " + table_str + " LIMIT 0")
        for desc in cur.description:
            col_names.append(desc[0])
        cur.close()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)
    return col_names
columnnames = get_table_col_names(rs_conn, "TABLE NAME")
print(columnnames)
```

**output**:

[*column names*]